# Understanding coalescence in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to understand coalescing memory. After some research, I learned that coalescing memory is to make sure the threads are accessing sequential memory, so that it can read all the data in 1 single transaction. And this data can be reused by other threads in the same group.

However, when I looked at a real example, I have no idea why the following function has a poor coalescence:

```
__kernel void mapSin(
    __global float* input,
    __global float* input,
    const unsigned int cout)
{
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);
    output[x * count + y] = sin(input[x * count + y]);
}
```

My guess is that the multiplication `x * count` causes discrete memory access. Am I right? And what is the way to improve this function so that it enables better coalescence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right that it is because `x * count` is causing each work item to read memory that is not adjacent to the other nearby work items. The wide reads from memory get partially used (and the remainder discarded, and you end up with serialized reads for each work item). `x` is the "faster moving" global_id in your code, so try instead making it id(1) and make y id(0) (and then also swap width and height where you enqueue the kernel). This will make `y` the id that changes by 1 for adjacent work items, which will make your memory accesses adjacent as well, which is the way to get coalesched memory access (one wide read can satisfy multiple work items; i.e. parallel reads).